# dynamic padding to <td>

Tags: asp.net

how to give padding to `<td>` from aspx.cs page
i want to give set

```
style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0px; left: 173px; height: 32px; width: 50px;"
```

this from `aspx.cs` page

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you should:

1. Add ID attribute to your <td> tag (for example ID="myControl")
2. Add runat="server" attribute to your <td> tag.

   `<td ID="myControl" runat="server"></td>`
3. Write following code in your aspx.cs file:

   `myControl.Attributes.Add("style", "position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0px; left: 173px; height: 32px; width: 50px;");`

Answer (score 0):

`<td>` is a static HTML element, I think you have to use that style for `DIV` or `SPAN`

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="div1" runat="server">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

in aspx.cs

```
div1.Attributes.Add("style", "position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0px; left: 173px; height: 32px; width: 50px;");
```